# disable pre-emptive swapping in windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, swap, pagefile

If I leave my XP pc for a while, it seems to swap most of my processes to disc. I come back to use it after X hours/days and each process takes 10-30s to get going as it loads it in off disc. It seems to pre-emptively swap applications to disc which may have made sense in an era of very low ram, but these days with plenty of ram to spare it seems harmful.

Short of installing more ram and disabling this swap file, is there any way to force windows to start swapping in a more sane way? e.g. don't swap processes pre-emptively?

Comment: as an addendum I got windows 7 and I haven't seen this problem since

Answer (score 2):

[Cacheman](http://www.outertech.com/how-to-speed-up-your-computer) can mitigate this, in my experience.